# When asking a group of people for the time, which of "Have you got the time?" and "Has any of you got the time?" is the more appropriate?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Let's say you go up to a group of people in the street and want to ask them the time; which of the above two sentences is the more appropriate? (are there any better alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

"*Have* any of you got the time?" would be the more appropriate way to say it, but "Have you got the time?" is perfectly acceptable since 'you' can act as a plural.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is perfect - I would normally expect: "Have any of you got the time?", which is a bit of a mixture of both your examples.

Answer (score -2):

I think that your examples work, even though they are not perfect as another user pointed out.
I think that

> Could you please tell me what the time is?

is better, but I believe that it is a matter of preference.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? Isn't my phrase valid?